# Testimonial section on homepage in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am designing a WordPress website, so I want to create a testimonial section on my front page which will show two or three testimonials and a more link to that page. I have successfully created a php page names testimonial.php and now want testimonials to appear there.. These testimonials are to b added from posts in WordPress. I am a beginner can anybody please properly explain how can I do it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create short code in functions.php and run the short code in home page template.

To create short code you will need [`add_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

To execute the shortcode , use [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

Comment: Can u give me hint how so please